# Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null: with cocos2d-x, no success despite many attempts?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, cocos2d-x

I would like to try a simple project using Eclipse Mobile For Developers, the NDK, Android SDK, and Cocos2d-x.

I have correctly set the paths in: cocos2d-x/create-android-project.sh :

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/Users/Empon/android"
```

and in the settings in Eclipse ("NDK path" from the Properties).

I followed the topics in stackoverflow but I can't make my project work. One thing that seems strange compared to one topic: I don't have anything below "libs".

I am on Mac Lion 10.7.4 (I downloaded the 64bit version of Eclipse), I have got no error in the project, the only errors are when I run the app on android (4.0.4, Alcatel ot 997), with these errors (here is a summary from 2 attempts):

```
04-22 22:19:09.079: E/AndroidRuntime(14321): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null
04-22 22:19:09.079: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
04-22 22:19:09.079: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-22 22:19:09.079: E/AndroidRuntime(14321):    at com.first.cocos2dx.samplecocos2dxandroid.<clinit>(samplecocos2dxandroid.java:37)
```

Would you know anything about this?

Thanks a lot

(source: http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started )

---

EDIT:

I have this issue now, after exporting correctly NDK_ROOT : `ndk-build: No such file or directory`!

> export NDK_ROOT=/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build: No such file or directory

But the file does exist in `android-ndk-r8e`... so, I double clicked on the file, it said `define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable` :

```
Empon$ /Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build ; exit;
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android NDK: Aborting
```

I have tried this in the Terminal :

in the Terminal :

```
Empon$ export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/Users/Empon/cocos2d-x/Monday3/ >> .bash_profile
Empon$ ./build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = :/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e >> .bash_profile
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /Users/Empon/cocos2d-x/Monday3/proj.android/../..
APP_ROOT = /Users/Empon/cocos2d-x/Monday3/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /Users/Empon/cocos2d-x/Monday3/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
./build_native.sh: line 89: :/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e >> .bash_profile
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build: No such file or directory
```

or just change the path in Android.mk :

```
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes                   
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/Classes
```

But still the same error with the Terminal... Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you didn't run the build_native.sh script

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I misunderstood the tutorial, I thought we had to choose one way to build (java/or c++). I have an issue though, with this command line : "please define NDK_ROOT" , the path is defined in Eclipse>Preferences>Android/NDK, where else should we specify it? Thanks again

Comment: @Paul I think you need to edit the build_native.sh file itself. It is at the top.

Comment: Sorry could you have a look to my edit, I copied the top of the file, I don't know where I should change it? Thanks m.ding

Comment: @Paul can you try open an ternimal and type `export NDK_ROOT="/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e"` then run the script again?

Comment: thanks a lot m.ding, I really appreciate your help, sorry to ask again, but I have got another issue in the Terminal: it does not find `ndk-build` that already is in android-ndk-r8e folder... I have edited my post to show you exactly what happened, would you have any idea about that? Thanks

Comment: @Paul I am not sure but `export NDK_ROOT=/Users/Empon/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build` doesn't looks right to me. `NDK_ROOT` should be defined without the ndk-build command.

Comment: Remove spaces in your path,  and for Windows machines it's ndk-build.cmd

Comment: I edited build_native.py on Windows machine, had to add parenthesis  in print method calls and fix indentation/spacing issue at another place. Script still pops error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
Android app is still crashing but I hope I will find a way around soon.